# Firebase Cloud Functions: Get user property values

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to store some data from the 'app_remove' event in the database.
It works for the standard information like appInfo.appInstanceId.

But how do I get the userProperty values, since they are objects?

```
exports.appremoved = functions.analytics.event('app_remove').onLog(event => {

  console.log(event.data);
  console.log(event.data.user.Selected_Games);

  const user = event.data.user;
  if (user != null) {
    if(user.userId != null){
      admin.database().ref('/user_events/'+user.appInfo.appInstanceId + "/" + "deviceId").set(user.userId);
    }

    admin.database().ref('/user_events/'+user.appInfo.appInstanceId + "/" + "app_remove").set(event.data.logTime);
    admin.database().ref('/user_events/'+user.appInfo.appInstanceId + "/" + "app_install").set(user.firstOpenTime);
  }
});
```

This is the result of the console.log of event.data

```
AnalyticsEvent {
  params: { firebase_conversion: 1, firebase_event_origin: 'auto' },
  name: 'app_remove',
  reportingDate: '20170719',
  logTime: '2017-07-19T10:57:12.920Z',
  user: 
   UserDimensions {
     deviceInfo: 
      { deviceCategory: 'mobile',
        deviceModel: 'WAS-LX1A',
        deviceTimeZoneOffsetSeconds: 7200,
        platformVersion: '7.0',
        userDefaultLanguage: 'it-it' },
     geoInfo: 
      { city: 'Milan',
        continent: '039',
        country: 'Italy',
        region: 'Lombardy' },
     appInfo: 
      { appId: 'com.example.example',
        appInstanceId: '000000',
        appPlatform: 'ANDROID',
        appStore: 'com.android.vending',
        appVersion: '1.12' },
     firstOpenTime: '2017-07-17T12:37:01.320Z',
     userProperties: 
      { Active_Notification: [Object],
        Referrer: [Object],
        Selected_Games: [Object],
        Selected_Sources: [Object],
        Selected_Topics: [Object],
        first_open_time: [Object],
        user_id: [Object] },
     bundleInfo: ExportBundleInfo { bundleSequenceId: 10, serverTimestampOffset: 693 } } }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

I did a console.log of that object (event.data.user.Selected_Games)

```
UserPropertyValue { value: '4', setTime: '2017-06-27T01:22:25.375Z' }
```

So to get the value

```
event.data.user.userProperties.Selected_Games.value
```